# Mamp MySQL doesn't work in second OS X user account

Tags: mysql, macos, mamp

I'm having an issue with MAMP on my Macbook Pro. When I try to start the servers in my new work OS X account, only the Apache server runs. My MySQL server won't start. I find this a little odd because Apache and MySQL run fine on the account that I originally used to install MAMP. I tried the typical:

```
killall -9 mysqld
```

but that didn't work. It actually returned a message saying:

```
No matching processes belonging to you were found
```

So it didn't look like mySQL was already running.

Answer (score 5):

I didn't want to re-install MAMP and MAMP Pro, so I decided to look into it a little further. It seemed like it could be a permissions issue. Here are the steps I took to fix the issue:

1. Open Applications folder, right click on MAMP, click Get Info.
2. Look at Sharing & Permissions. This is how mine looked:

   - "original osx user" - Read & Write
   - admin - Read & Write
   - everyone - Read Only
3. Click the lock icon in the bottom right corner to allow changes. Enter password.
4. Click the + icon in the bottom left corner.
5. In the new window that appears, highlight your current user and choose Select.
6. In the original window, highlight your current user that has been added to the Sharing & Permissions list.
7. Change the privilege for the newly added user to Read & Write.
8. Important Step: Make sure the user is completely highlighted, click the gear icon and select Apply to enclosed items...

This should give your newly added user the proper permissions, recursively, to allow MAMP's MySQL and Apache servers to run. I did this same process from MAMP Pro as well.

Comment: Thank you! Fix still works 7 years later (MAMP v6.8).  I'd previously done everything apart from that important step #8